# Global variable doesn't work! How do I get the same exact value of a variable outside of the function? NameError: name 'diva' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, variables, global-variables, undefined, nameerror

This is a script checking the National Provider Identifier numbers (NPI). So under def I've written the code but with the if **name** == "**main**" part I want to access the diva part from the function so the users input is checked and if the IPS is valid I want the output to be True and if it isn't valid False.

When I run my script I get NameError: name 'diva' is not defined under if__name__ == "**main**": I want my code outside of the function where I've written "diva" to have the same value.

The code:

```
def validate_pnr(ips):
    sum_odd = 0
    sum_even = 0
    total = 0 
    #global diva
    ips = ips.replace("-", "")
    ips = ips.replace(" ", "")
    ips = ips[::-1]
    
    for digit in ips[::2]:
        sum_odd += int(digit)

    for digit in ips[1::2]:
        digit = int(digit) * 2
        if digit >= 10:
            sum_even += (1+(digit % 10))
        else:
            sum_even += digit

    total = sum_odd + sum_even
    divide = total % 10 == 0
    diva = divide
 
    return diva and ips


if __name__ == "__main__":

    print("Welcome to National Provider Identifier numbers (NPI) validator")
    print("Write in the format (YYMMDD-NNNN):")
    answer= input("You want to try? (Y/N): ")

    while answer != "N":
        ips = input("Write in the format (YYMMDD-NNNN): ")
        while diva == True:  #Here I get the error
            validate_pnr(ips)
            answer = input("You want to try another one? (Y/N): ")
            if answer == "N":
                print("Program is executing...")
```

I've tried to use a global variable as you can see but I get the exact same NameError.
The script works well until I write in the IPS.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: as you have written it, the variable `diva` is scoped locally to the function `validate_pnr`. The line you commented out `global diva` doesn't fix the problem because there is no variable named `diva` in the global scope.

## Solution to question

So the quickest solution to your problem is to introduce a variable `diva` to the global scope. Here is what that looks like (I also made one change to print the results of the function `validate_pnr`):

```
# Define variable `diva` in the global scope (outside of a function).
# This fixes your problem and answers your question, but usage of 
# global variables is not best practice!
diva = True

def validate_pnr(ips):
    global diva

    sum_odd = 0
    sum_even = 0
    total = 0 
    ips = ips.replace("-", "")
    ips = ips.replace(" ", "")
    ips = ips[::-1]
    
    for digit in ips[::2]:
        sum_odd += int(digit)

    for digit in ips[1::2]:
        digit = int(digit) * 2
        if digit >= 10:
            sum_even += (1+(digit % 10))
        else:
            sum_even += digit

    total = sum_odd + sum_even
    divide = total % 10 == 0
    diva = divide
 
    return diva and ips


if __name__ == "__main__":

    print("Welcome to National Provider Identifier numbers (NPI) validator")
    print("Write in the format (YYMMDD-NNNN):")
    answer= input("You want to try? (Y/N): ")

    while answer != "N":
        ips = input("Write in the format (YYMMDD-NNNN): ")
        while diva == True:  # No error because `diva` is in global scope now.
            print('Result:', validate_pnr(ips))
            answer = input("You want to try another one? (Y/N): ")
            if answer == "N":
                    print("Program is executing...")
```

## Edit: solution based on comments

```
def validate_pnr(ips):

    sum_odd = 0
    sum_even = 0
    total = 0 
    ips = ips.replace("-", "")
    ips = ips.replace(" ", "")
    ips = ips[::-1]
    
    for digit in ips[::2]:
        sum_odd += int(digit)

    for digit in ips[1::2]:
        digit = int(digit) * 2
        if digit >= 10:
            sum_even += (1+(digit % 10))
        else:
            sum_even += digit

    total = sum_odd + sum_even

    return (total % 10 == 0)

def main():

    print("Welcome to National Provider Identifier numbers (NPI) validator")
    print("Write in the format (YYMMDD-NNNN):")
    answer = input("You want to try? (Y/N): ")

    while answer != "N":

        ips = input("Write in the format (YYMMDD-NNNN): ")
        is_valid = validate_pnr(ips)

        print(f'ips {ips} is valid: {is_valid}')

        answer = input("You want to try another one? (Y/N): ")
    
    print("Program is exiting...")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you it did work but I only get the IPS now backwards and the rest of the code in the function isn't getting through.
Example: when I write in 020313-4836 I get it backwards Result: 9904119020.
So you see the rest of the script doesn't run from the function (I think) .I don't get any Errors.

Comment: That's because your logic reverses the IPS in the function and returns the reversed IPS (when `diva` is true; when `diva` is false, the function returns false). I can rewrite the function to do what (I think) you want. I'm not going to change the main validation logic of the function, though, unless you can describe the rules for how the validation is supposed to be performed. Check my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked. It's just a small problem, when I write the ips when its valid it prints out: ips 981215-4721 is valid: True which is correct but when its not valid it writes that its False but it still prints out the "is valid" part. It isn't a big problem and my main problem is solved so once again thank you!